# Return a list of a YouTube Channel's videos in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, youtube-api

I am building an iOS app that allows a user to view all the videos in a YouTube Channel, see the thumbnail, viewpoint, and duration of the video and click to play them. I am using a custom UITableViewCell and it is working great but right now they are static cells. I would like to use the YouTube API to fill in the data for this. However, I cannot find a good example of how to do this. The basics are going to be accessing the YouTube API, getting the JSON and changing it into the TableViewCell however I cannot find any objective C examples for how I would go about this. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out some of the ray wenderlich tutorials like http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5 It's a little older but the json code is good. Once you have the json data you load it into your data object, for example an array, and call reloadData on the tableview object and it will display it.

Answer (score 0):

Good basic example right here - https://github.com/drice0331/YoutubeV3apiList